# How do I create multiple vulnerability scanners on the public cloud?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Let us say I have a large IP range (a x.x.x.x/8 CIDR). What would be a way to efficiently deploy multiple instances of vulnerability scanners on the public cloud to scan that IP range in a period of 1 month?
For calculations, assume one instance of the vulnerability scanner can complete 100 IP addresses a day.

I was looking at Nessus AMI, but the licensing is annual, leading to a opportunity cost of 11 months per licence.

Comment: Hi. I've flagged this as belonging on super user. While it is about vulnerability scanning the problem set is scaling, which is a development problem.

Comment: But knowing which security tools to load on that cloud solution requires security expertise.

Comment: What is your question? Which scanners are fastest, or how to scale scanners in the 'cloud'? I'm really not sure what you are asking.

Comment: How to create sufficient scale in the 'cloud' while considering licensing costs.

Answer (score 1):

You could build an OpenVAS Scanning Cluster as seen in this [proposed architecture](https://www.nopsec.com/blog/docker-based-openvas-scanning-cluster-improve-scope-scalability/).

Docker has a few cloud providers, such as AWS, Azure, DigitalOcean, Exoscale, GCE, Rackspace, Softlayer, and vCloud Air. You can also use self-hosted platforms such as Hyper-V, OpenStack (especially via CoreOS), and vSphere via Docker providers.

Check out a Docker implementation of an OpenVAS cluster here -- https://github.com/wcollani/openvas-8-docker

One old paper references some statements that may not be as accurate today about the latency introduced by Docker NAT -- IBM PDF: http://domino.research.ibm.com/library/cyberdig.nsf/papers/0929052195DD819C85257D2300681E7B/$File/rc25482.pdf -- but I suggest that you check out -- https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/dockernetworks/ -- or the network provider [weave](https://www.weave.works/) if you feel this is a concern.

One very-nice aspect to Docker is that you can remove the Docker instance in the cloud with your docker-machine provider, thus significantly reducing charges since you'll only be using the cloud instances when actively using your platform.

You may also want to check out what the Seccubus project has been up to -- https://www.seccubus.com/2016/04/08/OpenVAS-fixed/